# Make Thymeleaf th:field consume Lombok-generated boolean getter

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, lombok

I'm creating a simple Spring MVC app with Thymeleaf. Being lazy, I'm using Lombok as well. I have a simple DTO, passing to and from Thymeleaf:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TypeDto {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

but I'm getting the following error trying to access page:
`Bean property 'isActive' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?` It's failing in the following Thymeleaf snippet:

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isActive}"/></td>
```

If I'd rename `isActive` to `active` in both DTO and Thymeleaf template it works fine, so my guess Thymeleaf is trying to read property with `getIsActive`, which OFC doesn't exist. As much as I'm up for simple solutions, is there a way to leave boolean as `isActive` and still make Thymeleaf work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While typing this question, I've found out that if I change property matcher in Thymeleaf template itself from `isActive` to `active`, everything works as expected and no need to change anything on DTO level and below.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{active}"/></td>
```

Comment: Don't you encouter a problem while posting your form?

Comment: No. As long as I have only one property matching `active`, it works like a charm,

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'is' from the field name.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{Active}"/></td>
```